# playing sounds using EV3DEV without ev3dev2 in micropython

Tags: lego-mindstorms-ev3, pybricks-micropython

My current setup using the EV3 is a SPIK3R and trying to use it with this program:

```
#!/usr/bin/env pybricks-micropython
from pybricks.hubs import EV3Brick
from pybricks.ev3devices import (Motor, TouchSensor, ColorSensor,
                                 InfraredSensor, UltrasonicSensor, GyroSensor)
from pybricks.parameters import Port, Stop, Direction, Button, Color
from pybricks.tools import wait, StopWatch, DataLog
from pybricks.robotics import DriveBase
from pybricks.media.ev3dev import Image, SoundFile, ImageFile

ev3 = EV3Brick()
A = Motor(Port.A)
D = Motor(Port.D)
B = Motor(Port.B)
IR = InfraredSensor(Port.S4)

ev3.speaker.play_file(/home/robot/media/sound.wav)
```

I tried running the code butt all i got was a Syntax error.